Make the TerraformAsset constructor to process the Path as a Token As Opposed to one of the AssetType
Here is info about our technical development environment :
• Microsoft Visual Studio 2022
• .NET 6.0
• C# 10
• HashiCorp.Cdktf 0.16.3
• HashiCorp.Cdktf.Providers.Aws 14.0.4
• HashiCorp.Cdktf.Providers.Docker 7.0.1
• Amazon.Lambda.Core 2.1.0
• Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson 2.3.1
• Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents 2.6.0
The AWS Lambda project contains the following:
• Amazon.Lambda.Core 2.1.0
• Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson 2.3.1
• Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents 2.6.0
In my Windows Powershell window, I’ve run the following commands:

$Env:TF_VAR_blahLambdaAssetDirPath =“C:\Blah\Lambda\bin\Debug\net6.0\”


cdktf synth

Please keep in mind that the following code is coded in C#

   TerraformVariable blahLambdaAssetDirPath = new TerraformVariable(this, > > nameof(blahLambdaAssetDirPath), new
TerraformVariableConfig
    {
        Type = "string",
        Default = "ami-abcde123",
        Description = "Blah Lambda Asset Directory Path",

    });


    ITerraformAssetConfig assetConfig = new TerraformAssetConfig()
    {
        Path = blahLambdaAssetDirPath.StringValue
        ,
      Type = AssetType.ARCHIVE
      
    };
    TerraformAsset lambdaAsset = new TerraformAsset(this, "lambda-asset", assetConfig);


When I run the following from the Windows Powershell commandline:

cdktf synth

Using Visual Studio 2022 debug breakpoints, I noticed that the Path value will be set to the following:

Path = “${TfToken[TOKEN.3]}”

However, when the point of execution reaches the following line of code:

    TerraformAsset lambdaAsset = new TerraformAsset(this, "lambda-asset", assetConfig);


, the following error is thrown:

System.Exception: ‘ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ‘${TfToken[TOKEN.3]}’’

The problem is that the TerraformAsset constructor processes the Path as a AssetType of Archive which is problematic as the value is a Token when the point of execution reaches the aforementioned code.
What modifications to the aforementioned code do I have to make in order to make the TerraformAsset constructor to process the Path as a Token for now? (During execution like terraform apply, I will ensure that the relevant environment variables are set to the proper Directory paths)
